# Firestore Cloud Function with SendGrid - Substitutions doesn't show data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sendgrid

With some help I've successfully created a Cloud Function which sends an E-mail onCreate of a further document. My intention is that this e-mail shows the data from the document. My approach was to use substitutions in the SendGrid Template and to bind these to the data from the document in Firestore.

Firestore is storing its data under /requests and each doc has a randomly created ID. A doc is created every time a form is being submit.

As for now I successfully receive an email but without the wanted data/substitutions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.firestoreRequest = functions.firestore.document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const requestId = snap.id; // get the id
    const db = admin.firestore();

    return db.collection('requests').doc(requestId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        const request = doc.data();
        const msg = {
          to: 'fuhr@gmx.net',
          from: 'fuhr@gmx.net',

          templateId: 'd-3cd6b40a74f34b53d1633702107d2',
          substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
          substitutions: {
            name: request.name,
            lastname: request.lastname,
            email: request.email,
            package: request.package,
            date: request.date,
            text: request.text
            // and other custom properties here
          }
        };

        return sgMail.send(msg)
      })
      .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
      .catch(err => console.log(err) )
  });
```

SendGrid Template:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      Name: {{name}}<br>
      Family: {{lastname}}<br>
      Email: {{email}}<br>
      Package: {{package}}<br>
      Date: {{date}}<br>
      Text: {{text}}<br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that I was referring the wrong SendGrid Template type. Correct me if I'm wrong, but SendGrid isn't supporting the Legacy Email Template anymore and that's exactly the type of template I'm referring with substitutions.

> This setting refers to our original Email Templates. We now support more full featured transactional templates, with support for multiple templates, versioning, and more.

Instead of substitutions I had to use:

```
          dynamic_template_data: {
            name: request.name,
            lastname: request.lastname,
            email: request.email,
            package: request.package,
            date: request.date,
            text: request.text
            // and other custom properties here
          }
```

Comment: I did the same as you but, I receives Error: Bad Request from Cloud Functions, any idea?. Did you do anything else?